# Single text box and submit behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

I have a single text box with no submit button on form as below :

```
<html>
    <form action="http://www.google.com">
        <input type="text"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

when text box is selected and i press enter key form will get submitted and google page will be displayed.
however if i have two text box as bellow :

```
<html>
    <form action="http://www.google.com">
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="text"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

now if i press submit button nothing will happen.

**Can anyone explain here : 
 i) why form is get submitted in first case? 
ii) why form is not submitting in second case?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HTML 2.0 Specs](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2):

> When there is only one single-line text input field in a form, the
>   user agent should accept Enter in that field as a request to submit
>   the form.

The easiest way to disable this behavior is to add a hidden input field.

Comment: is this applies to only text box?

Comment: @Till adding a hidden input is not helping me. any idea?

Comment: Okay got it if i do like `<input type="text" style="display: none;" />` it will work, just `type="hidden"` will not.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because in the case of 2 input fields the browser does not know from which input field to process the Enter key as a form submit event. I am unsure but this could be the reason, additionally always use a button whenever you want to submit data to the server or you could define the submit event in one of the fields onClick function